# In Google Analytics, how do you only show data for a subset of pages?

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

I have a web application which consists of the application itself and marketing pages.

How do I show data only for the marketing pages? Location, OS, devices etc.

I have created a custom segment containing URLs for only the marketing pages, but how do I use the segment to view stats for only these pages? E.g. the table below the graph still show page visits for other pages.

[image]

---

This is how I defined the segment:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you applied the segment correctly.   It sounds to me like a problem with the segment definition.  Can you post that along with examples that are within it and not within it?

Comment: And could your segment be defined as "user that visited a marketing page"?   If so some users will have visited both types of pages and some page views for non-marketing pages will appear in reports.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, I think you're correct about your second comment. I guess I have to rething what I'm really looking for here. Thanks a bunch for taking the time.